# In typescript mikro-orm, how to define one-to one and one-to-many relationship for the same two tables?

Tags: sql, node.js, typescript, orm

I want to define an entity that contains `agents`, where each agent can have many unhandled event entities and one handled event entity. What I thought would work was

```js
import { Collection, Entity, ManyToOne, OneToMany, OneToOne, PrimaryKey, Property, Unique, Rel } from "@mikro-orm/core";

@Entity()
class AgentEntity {    
    @OneToOne(event => event.id, { nullable: true })
    lastEventHandled!: Rel<Event>;

    @OneToMany(() => Event, event => event.agent)
    unhandledEvents = new Collection<Event>(this);

@Entity()
class Event {
    @PrimaryKey({ autoincrement: true })
    id!: number;
    
    @ManyToOne()
    agent!: AgentEntity;
```

But this causes an issue with `OneToOne` and `ManyToOne` referencing the same `OneToMany` event property. I thought another way to solve this would be to log which event was handled as

```js
@Entity()
export class Event {
    @PrimaryKey({ autoincrement: true })
    id!: number;

    @Property()
    blockNumber!: number

    @Property()
    transactionIndex!: number

    @Property()
    logIndex!: number

    @Property()
    handled: boolean = false;

    @ManyToOne(() => AgentEntity)
    agent!: AgentEntity;

    constructor(agent: AgentEntity, event: EvmEvent, handled: boolean) {
        this.blockNumber = event.blockNumber;
        this.transactionIndex = event.transactionIndex;
        this.logIndex = event.logIndex;
        this.handled = handled;
        this.agent = agent;
    }
}
```

and redefine

```
    @OneToMany(() => Event, event => event.agent)
    events = new Collection<Event>(this);

    lastEventHandled(): Event | undefined {
        return this.events.getItems().filter(event => event.handled)[0]
    }

    unhandledEvents(): Event[] {
        return this.events.getItems().filter(event => !event.handled)
    }
```

but now there's an issue that I would have to manually clear the lastEventHandled from Events each time it is changed. Is there an easier way of doing this with type-orm?